# How Mysql join query on three tables with multiple colums?

Tags: mysql, join, relation

I have three tables like this:

**Table1**

```
english | hindi
--------------
 shakti  | शक्ति
 sharma  | शर्मा
```

**Table2**

```
eng| hin
------------------
 Jai |जय  
 Jo  | जो
```

**Table3*

```
name | commo| price  |
----------------------------------
 shakti  | jai  | 123.00 
 sharma  |jo  | 224.00 
 anil | paddy  | 1286.098
```

**I want to get result something like this*

```
 hindi| hin | price 
    --------------------------
     शर्मा    |   जो | | 224.00
```

Description :
  there is no primary key in any table
I want all records where
**Table2*  = 'जो'

I tried  but  I  am not able to fetch the data correctly. 
Please help.

Comment: what is your condition for required result?

Comment: It appears you are using English names/terms as keys. Why not use numeric (integer) values instead? That would likely make your keys shorter.

Comment: condition is that if  hin='जो'; then fetch data

Comment: `jo` corresponds to `sharma` then how can you get `shakti` in ouput

Comment: @G one u r right by mistaken i wrote there shakti it shoud be  sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) statement

```
select t1.hindi, t2.hin, t3.price
from table1 t1 inner join table3 t3 on t1.english=t3.name
inner join table2 t2 on t2.eng=t3.commo
where t2.hin='जो'
```

[fiidle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a6c87/1)

Answer (score 0):

There Must be a primary key and foreign key concept in table.
Give Primary key in all table and give relation using foreign key.

I think you get the point.